# Setting action parameter to form in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

Im using "Zend form". What should I do to get correct "action" parameter in my FORM tag?

For example, the form **Form_Search** used in **SearchController** in **indexAction**. Where and how should I set the action parameter to form to make it **"/my/app/directory/search/index"**?

Update: "action" parameter should be the same as the form will assume if not set. I just need the param in FORM to simplify JS coding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use setAction method of Zend_Form, e.g.:

```
$yourForm->setAction('/my/app/directory/search/index');
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

EDIT:
You can retrieve many info about the request, in an action, using $this->getRequest() method that returns an instance of `Zend_Controller_Request_Http`. For example, if to get basePath and everything between the BaseUrl and QueryString you can do:

```
    $infoPath = $this->getRequest()->getPathInfo();
    $basePath = $this->getRequest()->getBaseUrl();

    $yourForm->setAction($basePath . $infoPath);
```

`Zend_Controller_Request_Http` has other methods that might be useful to you.

Comment: Yes, this is what I want but what I DONT want is to write the path myself. I want something like $form->setAction($this->action->getUrl);

Comment: @Chvanikoff. I added more info in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `url()` view helper to create your action urls.

```
$view->url(array(
    'module'     => 'mymodule',
    'controller' => 'mycontroller',
    'action'     => 'myaction',
    'param1'     -> 'myvalue1',
    // etc
), 'default'); 
// 'default' here refers to the default route. 
// If you specify a custom route, then that route will be used to 
// assemble() the url.
```

Depending where you call `$form->setAction()`, you can access to the `$view` in different ways.

In the controller: `$this->view`

In the form itself: `$this->getView()`

In a view script: `$this`

In view helper extending `Zend_View_Helper_Abstract`: `$this->view`

Hope it helps!

Comment: I see now from your comments to @Marcin that you seem to want something that automatically detects the current url on which the form is being displayed. His suggestinon about getting the url from the `$request` object makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Just an addition to previous answers. Kind of "industry standard approach" is to render/validate/process the form all on the same page. Then there is no need to set the action as it's filled with current URL.

Exception is for example serch field in layout. Then use `$form->setAction($url)`. But always remember to **echo the form in the search action**. If the form value is invalid, ZF would expect you to render it in page with the errors. Or you can use `$form->getErrors()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
            `$this->setAttribs(array(
                'accept-charset' => 'utf-8',
                'enctype' => Zend_Form::ENCTYPE_URLENCODED,
                'method' => 'get',
                'action' => '/controller/action/param/attr'
            ))`
```